# Show that $\int_0^\pi f(\sin x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 2\int_0^{\pi/2}f(\sin x) \, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Any tips on how to show that $$\int_0^\pi f(\sin x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 2\int_0^{\pi/2} f(\sin x) \, \mathrm{d}x \text{ ?}$$

Comment: This doesn't hold for all $T$. Did you mean $T = \pi$?

Comment: Yes, my bad, gonna edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi f(\sin(x))\,dx&=\int_0^{\pi/2} f(\sin(x))\,dx+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} f(\sin(x))\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2} f(\sin(x))\,dx+\underbrace{\int_{\pi/2}^0 f(\sin(\pi-t))\,(-dt)}_{\text{after the substitution}\,\,x=\pi-t}\\\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2} f(\sin(x))\,dx+\int_0^{\pi/2} f(\sin(t))\,dt\\\\
&=2\int_0^{\pi/2} f(\sin(x))\,dx
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Split the integral:$$\int_{0}^{\pi}f(\sin(x)) = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(\sin(x)) + \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}f(\sin(x))$$

Shift one integral:

$$\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}f(\sin(x)) = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(\sin(x + \pi/2))$$

Reverse:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(\sin(x + \pi/2)) = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(\sin((\pi/2 - x) + \pi/2)) = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(\sin(\pi - x))$$

But since $\sin(x) = \sin(\pi - x)$ we can simplify:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}f(\sin(x)) = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(\sin(x))$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin \left( \frac{\pi}{4} + x \right) = \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{4} - x \right)  \text{.}  $$

Answer (score 1):

**Generalization**:

$$\int_0^{2a}f(x)\ dx=\int_0^af(x)\ dx+\int_a^{2a}f(x)\ dx$$

Now set $2a-x=u$ and what happens if $f(2a-x)=f(x)$