# How to calculate the floor integral $\int_0^{\pi}\lfloor\pi^2\cos^3x\rfloor\sin x\,dx$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, ceiling-and-floor-functions, trigonometric-integrals, bounds-of-integration

$$\int_0^{\pi}\lfloor\pi^2\cos^3x\rfloor\sin x\,dx$$ (where $\lfloor x \rfloor $ is the floor of $x$)

I thought of breaking into required bounds but its too lengthy. Moreover I had to take cube root and then $\cos$ inverse. Please give a hint.

Comment: @Landuros Your edit has affected the relevance of an already-posted answer.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523420/show-that-int-0-pi-f-sin-x-mathrmdx-2-int-0-pi-2f-sin-x-math/2523449#2523449

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Sorry if I disrupted anything, I'm just making sure people are using correct notation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since,

$$ \int_0^{2a}f(x)\,dx =\int_0^{a}\bigl(f(a+x)+f(a-x)\bigr)\,dx$$

$$ \implies\int_0^{\pi}\left\lfloor\pi^2\cos^3x\right\rfloor\sin x\,dx=\int_0^{{\pi}/{2}}\left(\left\lfloor-\pi^2\sin^3x\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\pi^2\sin^3x\right\rfloor\right)\cos x\,dx$$

Clearly, most of the terms will get cancelled out.

Comment: That is absolutely incredible! Where did you learn that identity?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Thank you. It was in my 12th class Mathematics and this identity itself is the foundation for

 $ \int_{-a}^{a}f(x)\,dx =
\begin{cases}
2 \int_0^{a}f(x)\,dx  & \text{if $f$ is even} \\
0 & \text{if $f$ is odd}
\end{cases} $

Comment: Given @Landuros’s edit to the original question, you might wish to update your notation to incorporate `\lfloor` and `\rfloor`

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Done :)