# On the way of solving Integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{x\sin^{2n}x}{\sin^{2n}x+\cos^{2n}x}dx$.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

**Question**

> For $n > 0$, Find 
>   $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{x\sin^{2n}x}{\sin^{2n}x+\cos^{2n}x}dx$$

**My Approach**

Let
 $I_{n}$  =$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{x \sin^{2n}x}{\sin^{2n}x+\cos^{2n}x}dx$$
I$_{n}$=$\int_{0}^{2\pi}$$\frac{\left(2\pi-x\right)\sin^{2n}x}{\sin^{2n}x+\cos^{2n}x}dx$$\Longrightarrow$2I$_{n}=$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}$$\frac{2\pi \sin^{2n}x}{\sin^{2n}x+\cos^{2n}x}dx$
$\Longrightarrow$I$_{n}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\pi \sin^{2n}x}{\sin^{2n}x+\cos^{2n}x}dx$

I am stuck here!

Comment: @MyGlasses Not a big deal!.Thanks for other improvements

Comment: Use twice https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523420/show-that-int-0-pi-f-sin-x-mathrmdx-2-int-0-pi-2f-sin-x-math/2523449#2523449

Comment: Then https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3xdx/439856#439856

Comment: @labbhattacharjee This is very much helpful.Now i think i can solve the question?Thanks!

Comment: I think in this question $n$ has to be a natural number rather than any real number greater than zero. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If in the integral
$$I_n = \int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{x \sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \, dx,$$
we set $x \mapsto 2\pi - x$ it can be readily seen that
$$I_n = \pi \int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{\sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \, dx.$$

Note the integrand
$$f(x) = \frac{\sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x},$$
is both an even and periodic function with a fundamental period of $\pi$. If $f$ is a continuous bounded function with period $\mathfrak{a}$, then
$$\int^{b + \mathfrak{a}}_b f(x) \, dx = \int^\mathfrak{a}_0 f(x) \, dx,$$
where $b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Using this result repeatedly on our integral we have
\begin{align*}
I_n &= \pi \int^{-\pi + 2\pi}_{-\pi} \frac{\sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \, dx \qquad \text{(periodic with period $2\pi$)}\\
&= \pi \int^\pi_{-\pi} \frac{\sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \, dx\\
&= 2\pi \int^\pi_0 \frac{\sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \, dx \qquad \text{(since it is even)}\\
&= 2\pi \int^{-\pi/2 + \pi}_{-\pi/2} \frac{\sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \, dx \qquad \text{(periodic with period $\pi$)}\\
&= 4 \pi \int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{\sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \, dx \qquad \text{(since it is even)}.
\end{align*}

Now setting $x \mapsto \dfrac{\pi}{2} - x$ gives
$$I_n = 4 \pi \int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{\cos^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \, dx.$$
Thus
$$I_n + I_n = 4\pi \int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \, dx = 4\pi \int^{\pi/2}_{0} \, dx,$$
or
$$I_n = \int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{x \sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \, dx = \pi^2.$$

Comment: What would happen if n is real number greater than zero

Comment: When $n$ is a natural number the integrand always remains a continuous bounded function on the interval $[0,2\pi]$. If $n > 0$ where $n$ is real there are many (in fact infinitely many) values for which this will no longer be the case. If, for example, $n = 1/2$, on the interval $[0,2\pi]$ the integrand is unbounded at the points $x = 3\pi/4$ and $7\pi/4$ meaning the definite integral is no longer proper (it becomes improper) and as a result may no longer exist (that is, it diverges).